# JSON Decoder in custom pipeline is not working

Tags: c#, biztalk

I am using BizTalk+ESB. I send a request to a REST service. Using this pipeline. [image: send pipeline]

Which uses the `JSONEncoder`. The rest service posts a message in the event log, letting me know the process was completed. The issue is, on the response, I get this error:

> "The content type application/json; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8)."*

This is the response pipeline:

[image: receive pipeline]

It acts as if the `JSONDecoder` is not processing the response message.

The request is made using ESB Itinerary, and a WCF Web Service in BizTalk.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE - The call to the Rest service is in an Itinerary Service. WCF_WebHttp was not in the list of selections. Selected WCF-BasicHttp.

Now I receive the error: "There was a failure executing the response(send) pipeline: "PTwoMapPipeline.Part2RetMapPipeline, PTwoMapPipeline, Version=1.0.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7de7b3b357ccad5e" Source: "XML assembler" Receive Port: "WcfReceivePort_WCFInitiator/Service1" URI: "/WCFInitiator/Service1.svc" Reason: The document type "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/#Envelope" does not match any of the given schemas."

on the return Pipeline in my receive location. (Two way). Does this mean I need to add an Envelope schema. The Message is set in Receive location to use the body.

Comment: `application/soap+xml` hints what to do. Try to change request content type to `application/json`.

Comment: What send port adapter are you using?

Comment: WCF-WSHttp ....

Comment: Please update your question with actual code you tried and the challenge with that here so we may best assist you here.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss  This is BizTalk.  There is very little code apart from what he has shared so far, what was missing is what adapter he was using and any configuration settings on that.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - perhaps a/another form of "code" here on how it gets called but anything may help here perhaps on how the c# is calling it

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss No c# involved here.  All out of the box configurable components for this solution so far as I can see.  You can create custom components for BizTalk, and then you could use c#, or various other languages, including Java

Comment: I think you are going to have to give more details about the web service you are calling.  Note: The first error you got was on the response, the new error looks to be on the send,.  Also is this on a send port or a receive location?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the WCF-WebHttp Adapter for a RESTful service.  See [WCF-WebHttp Adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/wcf-webhttp-adapter) (Microsof.com)

> Microsoft BizTalk Server uses the WCF-WebHttp adapter to send messages to RESTful services. The WCF-WebHttp send adapter sends HTTP messages to a service from a BizTalk message. The receive location receives messages from a RESTful service. For GET and DELETE request, the adapter does not use any payload. For POST and PUT request, the adapter uses the BizTalk message body part to the HTTP content/payload.

The WCF-WSHttp is expecting a SOAP envelope and XML see [What Is the WCF-WSHttp Adapter?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/what-is-the-wcf-wshttp-adapter) (Microsof.com).

> The WCF-WSHttp adapter provides full access to the SOAP security, reliability, and transaction feature